# Simulated raytrace in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I have an application where I have a camera attached to the end of a 5-DOF robot arm (X, Y, Z, yaw, pitch). The robot arm is moving the camera around a fixed object (0,0,0) for inspection purposes. Given the position and orientation of the camera, is it possible to detect where on the object the camera is seeing? For example, I would like to know whether the axis of the camera is intersecting the object, and if so, determine the exact coordinates of the object the camera axis is intersecting.

Given the known camera axis (position/orientation), is it possible to extend a line along the +x-axis and see where it hits the fixed object (if it all)?

I should be able to calculate positions along the +x-axis moving outwards from the camera frame. However, I do not know how to check if these points are contained inside of the fixed object of interest. Would also be nice if something already existed for this, or at least something I can use to help.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16817/simulated-raytrace-in-gazebo/) by [JoshMarino](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2831/joshmarino/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could take a look at a couple of things:

- [Logical camera](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/worlds/logical_camera.world), which gives you the exact coordinates of every model contained within its frustum
- [RayShape::GetIntersection](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1RayShape.html#a2864740586b30cce11e47df42cbd3729), which you could use to implement your own plugin that returns the name and position of the first model that intersects a line coming out of the camera.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The gazebo Scene class has a [FirstContact](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/40c062da7dcc0ca6977a420cc7e66cd7a4f9f9eb/gazebo/rendering/Scene.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#Scene.cc-1099) function that probably helps you achieve what you want. If you want to use the camera's optical axis, set the mousePos to (0, 0). The last arg gives the intersection point

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1